# How to filter hover on a chart in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I'm trying to make a doughnut progress chart in ChartJS. I want to show the percentage of completion (i.e. 5% completed).

Currently, I have a chart with data `[5, 95]` because (from what I know), ChartJS doesn't allow just adding in the percentage and it filling out the rest of the chart with a gray data line, so I had to add in the `95` datapoint.

[image]

I've gotten the tooltip to not show on the `95` portion of the chart using tooltip filter, but I would like to now prevent the background from changing colors when I hover over it on the `95` portion data point only. Currently, it looks like this on hover, which I want to fix:

[image]

To summarize, I want to allow the actual progress data point (`5`) to be able to change colors on hover, but not the other part of the chart since its just a place holder to show what 5% looks like out of 100.

```
            var config = {
                type: 'doughnut',

                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [
                            studentProgress, (100 - studentProgress),
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "#646c9a",
                            "#FDFDFD"
                        ],
                        hoverBorderWidth: 0,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                    }],
                    labels: [
                        'Course Progress',
                        'Todo',
                    ],
                },
                options: {
                    cutoutPercentage: 75,
                    responsive: true,
                    circumference: Math.PI,
                    rotation: Math.PI,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                        position: 'top',
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'test'
                    },
                    animation: {
                        animateScale: true,
                        animateRotate: true
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        enabled: true,
                        intersect: false,
                        mode: 'nearest',
                        bodySpacing: 5,
                        yPadding: 10,
                        xPadding: 10,
                        caretPadding: 0,
                        displayColors: false,
                        backgroundColor: '#5d78ff',
                        titleFontColor: '#ffffff',
                        cornerRadius: 4,
                        footerSpacing: 0,
                        titleSpacing: 0,
                        filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                            var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                            if (label == "Todo") {
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                     }
                }
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById('chart_progress').getContext('2d');
            var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well? Also, what is `studentProgress` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hoverBackgroundColor. Just use the same color code for the grey.

```
backgroundColor: [
  "#646c9a",
  "#FDFDFD"
],

hoverBackgroundColor: [
  "#8389ae",
  "#FDFDFD"
],
```

Disadvantage: You have to think of a highlighted color code for your other datasets. It might be easier with rgba values so you only have to change the alpha value and not calculate or think of another color code.